# How do I define the target for _addButton?

Tags: magento

How do I define the target for _addButton? Below is the code I am using. I read the Magento docs located here but they didn't have this info: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Adminhtml/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container.html#method_addButton

```
 $this->_addButton('rebuild_files', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('core')->__('Rebuild Special Cache'),
    'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'http://mysite.com/page/\')',
    'class'     => 'rebuild',
));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting a target is not possible because a container's buttons are not inside a form, and it is the form's target that makes a difference. Furthermore that button doesn't trigger any form but uses javascript to direct the browser (hence the `setLocation` bit). Magento admin has a convenience function for what you want called `popWin`, it is shorthand for [`Window.open`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) so the second parameter is the target window name.

```
$this->addButton('rebuild_files', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('core')->__('Rebuild Special Cache'),
    'onclick'   => 'popWin("http://mysite.com/page/", "_blank")',
    'class'     => 'rebuild',
));
```

---

PS. `_addButton` is a protected method. It is better to use the public `addButton` in case another developer should attempt to change it's behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the insight and education into public vs protected methods.

Comment: popWin opens in a new window. Is there an option for opening into a new tab?

Comment: I figured it out, you just use: window.open instead off popWin